# Find growing realloc with valgrind

Tags: linux, valgrind, memory-leaks, realloc

I have a program whose use of memory grows by 6Mb every minute. I've ran valgrind on it and cannot find any leaks. So I suspect that it's some kind of realloc inside the graphic libraries I use (and of which I do not have the source). It's a 32 bit program, so it dumps core after it goes over 2Gb.

Is there some kind of option that will tell me something like: "Every time MyFunc is called, the memory grows by N bytes", and sort them out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wasted memory is not necessarily detectable as a leak. Fortunately Valgrind has many faces beside the familiar leak-finding one. [Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) is your friend. Use it, take some detailed snapshots and look at places where most allocations happen.